# problem: mainloop and function for config label

Tags: python, function, tkinter, time, label

I am trying to make a program that gives me attention each 20 min then break 5 min, everything looks easy but it doesn't work with me:(

can you find the problem
this is the main function:

```
sec=1200
def run():
    global sec
    if sec >=0:
        m,s=divmod(sec,60)
        lblmin.config(text=str(m).zfill(2))
        lblsec.config(text=str(s).zfill(2))
        sec -= 1
        root.after(1000,run)
        if sec==-1:
            ask=messagebox.showinfo("break 5 min!")           
            sec=300

    root.mainloop()
```

the problem actually not in the timer, it work but when 20 min finish it does not start again 
seem the function doesn't call back again

Comment: Move `root.after(1000,run)` at the end of your function `def run()`. It must beneath `.messagebox(...`.

Comment: stovfl , thank you so much it works!

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: If you come along this question, can you confirm that a `.messagebox...` cancels a `.after(...`.